# Error in fitQmapDIST in R

Tags: r

I am using qmap in R. I have obs data(obs) and model output(an) both are in  data frame with single row and single column. When I use the formula
`fitQmapDIST(obs,an,dist="GammaDist")` 
I get the following error:

[1]

> "Error in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs =
>   data,
>    : \n  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'\n" attr(,"class")

[1]

> "try-error" attr(,"condition")

```
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn
= fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth, lower = lower,     upper = upper, ...):
 L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'>
```

> Error in xx[!xx.NULL][[1]] :
>
> > subscript out of bounds

Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

try using the `sqrt` function as follows:

```
qmb4.fit <- fitQmap(sqrt(obsprecip),sqrt(modprecip),
                    method="DIST",qstep=0.001,
                    transfun="bernexp")
qmb4 <- doQmap(sqrt(futprecip),qmb4.fit)^2
```